# Designing Adjacency List or Parent-child relationship in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design

I'm trying to maintain child quote id and their parent quote id. I want to store two child-quotation with their parent quotation id, so I will be able to query which quotation are in child-parent relationship.

I'm confused with the design, should i keep first parent_id as NULL, means If child itself is parent, like employee is manager or keep it parent quote id same as child quote id.

I've made two design with NULL and with same child quote id as parent quote id.

Which will make my design simple and querying easier.

```
create table quotelist
(
  pk_aquotelistid int primary key identity(1,1),
  quoteid int,
  parent_quoteid int
);

insert into quotelist values(1,1), (2,1),(3,1);
insert into quotelist values(4,4), (5,4);
insert into quotelist values(6,6), (7,4);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c4ad9/1

OR

```
create table quotelist
(
  pk_aquotelistid int primary key identity(1,1),
  quoteid int,
  parent_quoteid int
);

insert into quotelist values(1,NULL), (2,1),(3,1);
insert into quotelist values(4,NULL), (5,4);
insert into quotelist values(6,NULL), (7,4);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0ba5f/1

Answer (score 0):

I think using NULL in `parent_quoteid` is more natural way and no one has to remember to add `quoteid != parent_quoteid` in every query, to exclude records where there is no parent_quote_id.

Moreover, once the parent_quoteid is NULL, such a record need not be inserted in the table. Such records can be obtained with a `LEFT JOIN` of quote table with quotelist table on `quote.quoteid = quotelist.parent_quoteid` where `quotelist.parent_quoteid IS NULL`. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to make parent quotes have parent_quoateid = null, then your WHERE clause to find parent quotes is (subject to your particular SQL dialect):

```
WHERE parent_quoteid = NULL
```

And for child quotes is:

```
WHERE parent_quoteid <> NULL
```

If you choose to set parent_quoteid to be the quote ID for parents, then your where clause looks rather similar; `WHERE quoteid = parent_quoteid` or `WHERE quoteid <> parent_quoteid`.

The standard for many-to-many relationships would be that if an item isn't in a relationship, it shouldn't have a row at all (consider renaming "quoteid" to "child_quoteid", and see if it still makes sense to have the row). The various relationship types (one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-many) are the only design patterns I know of for databases, let alone patterns which dictate simplicity.

But, you didn't ask if the row should be present or not. You asked if parent_quoteid should be null or not. So let's examine query performance and ease of querying.

If this particular choice was going to impact performance or how easy it is to query the table, you'd want to use NULL to indicate parent quotes; fewer fields and indexes would be involved for queries to determine parent vs child.

If you're going to need to join this table with a table of quotes, I would point out that not using NULL for parent quotes could lead to a situation where the database has to work with 3 fields instead of two in order to perform the join. If you don't use NULL, you'll drag in the quoteid field when you could otherwise just use parent_quoteid and the field from the table you're joining against.